# need help-variable creation in Python

Tags: python, variables

I want to create variables as `a1`,`a2`,`a3`...`a10`.
For that I used a for loop. As the variable in loop increments I need to create a variable as above.

Can anyone give me an idea?

At the time of creation I also need to be able to assign values to them.

That's where I'm getting syntax error.

Comment: Why don't you use an array for that?

Comment: Posting the code that raises SyntaxError would be a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following what S.Lott said, you can also use a dict, if you really nead unique names and that the order of the items is not important:

```
data = {}
for i in range(0, 10):
  data['a%d' % i] = i

>>>data
{'a1': 1, 'a0': 0, 'a3': 3, 'a2': 2, 'a5': 5, 'a4': 4, 'a7': 7, 'a6': 6, 'a9': 9, 'a8': 8}
```

I would add that this is very dangerous to automate variable creation like you want to do, as you might overwrite variables that could already exist.

Answer (score 13):

Usually, we use a list, not a bunch of individual variables.

```
a = 10*[0]
a[0], a[1], a[2], a[9]
```

Answer (score 2):

`globals()` returns the global dictionary of variables:

```
for i in range(1,6):
    globals()["a%i" % i] = i

print a1, a2, a3, a4, a5      # -> 1 2 3 4 5
```

But frankly: I'd never do this, polluting the namespace automagically is harmful. I'd rather use a list or a dict.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the exec function:

```
for i in range(0,10):
   exec("a%d=%d" % (i,i))
```

Not very pythonic way of doing things.

Comment: (I didn't downvote) This is correct, but it's not really helpful for a Python programmer wannabe. The questions hints at a need for guidance.

Comment: exec is not a function (in 2.x); you don't need the parentheses around it.

Comment: @Martin v. Löwis: putting them works in 2.5.2 ... Anyway the code solves the question, but I agree with ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ, there should be also a 'pythonic' hint ;)